# How to continue excute next if statement when the former if statement have an error

Tags: java

Here are my codes.

```
try{
    if("**".equals(state[i][j-1])){
        state[i][j-1] = String.valueOf(stopState);
        stopState++;
        willBeInitialized[i][j-1] = true;
    }
    if("**".equals(state[i+1][j-1])){
        state[i+1][j-1] = String.valueOf(stopState);
        stopState++;
        willBeInitialized[i+1][j-1] = true;
    }
    if("**".equals(state[i+1][j])){
        state[i+1][j] = String.valueOf(stopState);
        stopState++;
        willBeInitialized[i+1][j] = true;
    }
    if("**".equals(state[i][j+1])){
        state[i][j+1] = String.valueOf(stopState);
        stopState++;
        willBeInitialized[i][j+1] = true;
    }
    if("**".equals(state[i-1][j+1])){
        state[i-1][j+1] = String.valueOf(stopState);
        stopState++;
        willBeInitialized[i-1][j+1] = true;
    }
    if("**".equals(state[i-1][j])){
        state[i-1][j] = String.valueOf(stopState);
        stopState++;
        willBeInitialized[i-1][j] = true;
    }
}catch(Exception a){
    //continue next if statements;
}
```

What should I write in the catch scope?
Or whether I should rewrite the statement? And how?

Comment: Surely there must be a way to *generalize* the code such that there is *less repetition*? I would suggest using a (nested) loop. Then, with the simpler code, it should be trivial to add the appropriate edge-case checking.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: @user2864740 But it seems troublesome to use loop to check edge-case.Oh,my English is poor,what should I do to express my thoughts?

Comment: @yhc If you *expect* an error, handle it appropriately. In this case the only code that *can* throw an Exception is an IOOBE from the array access. **Exceptions aren't meant to catch coding errors.** However, if a (nested) loop is used, then suddenly a *single if/expression* can be used to *prevent* all the IOOBEs, because it's been generalized! This makes the code *less troublesome* than error-prone copy-and-paste. (And no, Java does not have any concept of "On Error Resume Next".)

Comment: (Although I'm curious what the *actual* problem is, because it looks as though `"**"` is a sentinel *wall* value? If sentinels are used correctly - and there is a wall around everything - then there should not be an IOOBEs to begin with!)

Comment: @user2864740 I'm writing a project which require me to achieve a Chinese Chapter(or Halma?) in console.An "**" represents the state where no pieces is put.

Comment: Besides,how to use (nested) loop to simplify my code?I can't think it out.

Comment: @user2864740 I just forget to @ you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is, you don't; if you want an exception in one part of the code to not cause another part to be skipped over, you have to put them in different try blocks. In your case, however, there is an elegant solution, looping to represent many different try blocks with a single block of code:

```
for (int k = i - 1; k <= i + 1; k++) {
    for (int l = j - 1; l <= j + 1; l++) {
        if (l - j == k - i) continue;
        try {
            if("**".equals(state[k][l])){
                state[k][l] = String.valueOf(stopState);
                stopState++;
                willBeInitialized[k][l] = true;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //do nothing, loop to next try block
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't ever think of a good reason to catch a top-level Exception, and this case is no different. I don't understand why the try/catch block is being used.

Comment: Catching the Exception is simply what the asker did, and I copied it. It wasn't part of the question.

Comment: In fact,I don't know more effective method to achieve my goal.I'm only a beginner..And is there  anything I can do to support your answer?It's the first time I log in this website,so I am not familiar with the rules and operations.

Comment: @Saposhiente I've just found "l == k" should be replaced by "l - j == k - i".Thank you all the same.

Comment: As the asker of the question there should be a button to mark it as the answer chosen by the asker.

Comment: For better ways to achieve your goal, that depends on what your goal is. As many people have pointed out, it is unclear why you need to catch an Exception at all. If you explained that, then we might be able to provide something better.

Answer (score 0):

I would kindly suggest to rewrite your code with less repetition. You keep checking for the same condition in different cells of `state` array. So I would suggest something like this:

```
for(k=i-1;k<i+1;k++){
   for(l=j-1;l<j+1;l++){
      try{
         if("**".equals(state[k][k])){
            state[k][l] = String.valueOf(stopState);
            stopState++;
            willBeInitialized[k][l] = true;
         }
      }catch(Exception e){
         //Even if you get an exception while the if statement is evaluated,
         //the loop will continue to execute the next if snippet
         continue;
      }
   }
}
```

Of course I cannot guarantee that this is the snippet you need, but I think you get the logic I propose.

Hope I helped!